# PreferenceFragmens inside FragmentTabHost are not inflated

Tags: android, fragment-tab-host, preferencefragment

I want to place a couple of `PreferenceFraments` into a `FragmentTabHost`. Based on existing standard examples the code is as follows.

**Layout XML (partial):**

```
<android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="480dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="480dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
```

**Main activity (in onCreate):**

```
tabHost = (FragmentTabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
tabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), android.R.id.tabcontent);
tabHost.addTab(
  tabHost.newTabSpec("t1").setIndicator(getString(R.string.first), null),
  FirstFragment.class, null);
tabHost.addTab(
  tabHost.newTabSpec("t2").setIndicator(getString(R.string.second), null),
  SecondFragment.class, null);
```

**The problem:** The tab host is created with 2 empty tabs (only labels are shown), because (if I understand correctly) it's supposed that I should inflate fragments in their corresponding `onCreateView` methods.

BUT they are `PreferenceFragments`, so they are inflated in `onCreate`:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(getActivity(), R.xml.first, false);

  // this is the method which inflates the layout according to the docs
  addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.first);
  getPreferenceManager().getSharedPreferences().registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
}
```

So, **the question is** what should I write in the `onCreateView` in order to get inflated preferences inside the tabs? Or maybe I should somehow tell the system that the preference screen will create all its views from XML?

All examples use `inflater.inflate(layoutResId, ...)` with a custom resource ID, but in this case there should be some underlying layout provided by the system (library), as well as I'm not sure if the standard inflater is ok for preference layout inflation from a preference XML.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
  // return inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.list_content, container, false);
  return ???;
}
```

The commented string does not help (tabcontent remains empty). Also, by using `android.R.layout.list_content`, it suggests minimum API level 11, but I use the support library in order to support older Android versions as well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you want override PreferenceFragments onCreateView method but you don't know what to return? Did i get it right? if that's so, return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

Comment: I have tried this. It did not work (preferences are not inflated).

Comment: Maybe custom PreferenceFragment is answer to your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20934265/change-the-background-color-of-preferencefragment/20979255#20979255 it inflates preferences inside onCreatView() method